# How to shuffle a SoundCloud set?

Tags: soundcloud

I know that it's possible to shuffle a user’s likes, though what about sets?

Seeing that sets are basically a playlist of sounds, how would it be possible to shuffle these songs?

Answer (score 2):

**April 2015 - EDITED**

SoundCloud added a feature to this, on the set page you can locate a shuffle button, see the image:

[image: soundcloud shuffle button]

---

**OLD ANSWER**

1. To shuffle my sets I have used this webplayer: http://mycloudplayers.com/ . It has a shuffle option in the bottom of screen:
   [image]
2. Another option are this script (if you know how to run a javascript in the browser): https://gist.github.com/rctay/9829266

Comment: Is this still an option? I can't find it

Comment: Hmm, apparently it's in the bottom playback bar now